# duplicate array validator in FormArray in Reactive form in angular

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I am adding `Alias` onclick of `addInputs`() method , basically adding new input text field with some conditions.

For this, I am trying to create `custom duplicate array validator directive` (synchronous or asynchronous formArray validator). It means a `Alias formArray` should validate the text in current input with other elements in `Alias formArray`. If no duplicates then add new input otherwise alert duplicate text;

alias = ['abc', 'abc']  <--- if entered text matches with others, validaton failed.

### .ts

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
        profileForm: FormGroup;
        aliaseS: FormArray;
        myInputs: FormArray;

        constructor(
            private formbuilder: FormBuilder
        ) {
            this.profileForm = this.formbuilder.group({
                firstName: ['', Validators.required],
                lastName: [''],
                contact: this.formbuilder.group({
                    mobileNo: [''],
                    state: [''],
                    city: ['']
                }),
                aliases: this.formbuilder.array([
                    this.formbuilder.control('')//add duplicate array Validator
                ]),
                myInputs: this.formbuilder.array([
                    this.formbuilder.control('') //add duplicate array Validator
                ])
            })
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            this.aliaseS = this.profileForm.get('aliases') as FormArray;
            this.myInputs = this.profileForm.get('myInputs') as FormArray;
        }

        updateProfile() {
            this.profileForm.patchValue({
                firstName: 'affff',
                contact: {
                    mobileNo: '99898981'
                }
            })
            console.warn(this.profileForm.value);
        }
        onSubmit() {
            console.warn(this.profileForm.value);
        }

        getAliases() {
            return this.profileForm.get('aliases') as FormArray;
        }

        addInputs(key) {
//if duplicate array Validator  Validates as false then add row otherwise error

            if (key === 'aliases') {
           // if no duplicate text then
           this.aliaseS.push(this.formbuilder.control(''));
            } else if(key === 'myInputs '){
                 // if no duplicate text then
           this.myInputs.push(this.formbuilder.control(''));
            }
        }
        deleteAlias(pos) {
            this.aliaseS.removeAt(pos);
        }
    }
```

### .html

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <label>First Name:
        <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" required />
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label>
        Last Name:
        <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
    </label>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="col-12" formGroupName="contact">
        <h3> Contacts</h3>
        <br/>
        <label>
            Mobile No
            <input type="text" formControlName="mobileNo">
        </label>
        <br/>
        <label>
            State
            <input type="text" formControlName="state">
        </label>
        <br/>
        <label>
            City
            <input type="text" formControlName="city">
        </label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="col-12"  formArrayName="aliases">
        <h3> Aliases</h3>
        <br/>
        <button type="button" (click)="addInputs('aliases')">Add Alias</button>

        <br/>
        <div *ngFor="let address of aliaseS.controls; let i = index;">
            <label>
                Alias:
                <input type="text"  [formControlName]="i" >
                <span (click)="deleteAlias(i)"> Delete</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12"  formArrayName="myInputs">
        <h3> myInputs</h3>
        <br/>
        <button type="button" (click)="addInputs('myInputs')">Add myInputs</button>
        <div *ngFor="let address of myInputs.controls; let i = index;">
            <label>
                Alias:
                <input type="text"  [formControlName]="i" >
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-12" >
            <br>
            <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" (click)="updateProfile()">Update</button>
    </div>
</form>
<br />
<br />
<p>{{profileForm.status}}</p>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Updated question, Basically, I am dynamically adding input field on click with conditions that current input field value should not match with other input field values in formArray. For this, a duplicateValidator.directive.ts, I am trying to create which will be added in FormArray and validate.

Comment: A directive, even a validator, are not the right tool for that job. All you need is a few lines of code in your addInputs method.

Comment: Thanks, I am figuring if such directive is possible . Meanwhile, Can you help me with the method to check duplicates in formArray for current scenario.

Comment: `hasDuplicates(): boolean {
    const aliases: Array<string> = this.getAliases().value;
    return new Set(aliases).size !== aliases.length;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I have little bit refactor your code and now it's working as expected. For duplicate validation I have used [unique validator of rxweb validation framework](https://github.com/rxweb/rxweb/blob/master/test/reactive-form-validators/validator/unique.validator.spec.ts).

Here is the code to applying unique validator on FormControl.

```js
addControl(){
            return this.formbuilder.group({
             name:this.formbuilder.control('',RxwebValidators.unique())});
        }
```

That's it.

On the HTML side I have used disabled attribute and check that the FormArray is valid or not. If it's valid then button will be enabled and user can enter new element.

Here is the code of HTML:

```html
 <button type="button" [disabled]="!profileForm.controls.aliases.valid" (click)="addInputs('aliases')">Add Alias</button>
```

I have transformed your code in stackblitz and did the changes, please refer the **[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nt5agm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**